# getting the old value of a cell when reading excel file using xlsx in node js

Tags: node.js, excel, xlsx

I read and write to an excel file in node js using "xlsx" library.
some of the cells in the excel file have formulas that depend on other cells, for example: B1=A1.
using my example, when I write to A1 , B1 supposed to get the value of A1.
when I open the excel file with Microsoft office Excel everything looks fine and B1 has the value of A1 as expected, but if read the file from the code using node js B1 has its old value.
if I open the file in Microsoft office Excel and save it,and than read it from node js so B1 has the correct value.
this problem only occurs on cells with formulas.
Here is my code:

```
const xlsx = require("xlsx")

function write_answers_to_excel(){
    var execl_file =  xlsx.readFile("./uploads/input.xlsx");
    var sheet_name = execl_file.SheetNames[0]

    var sheet_A = execl_file.Sheets[sheet_name];
    sheet_A ['A1'].v = 5;

    var res_file_path = "./tmp/res.xlsx";
    xlsx.writeFile(execl_file, res_file_path);
    console.log("Finish writing answers to excel");
    
    var execl_with_answers =  xlsx.readFile(res_file_path);
    sheet_A = execl_with_answers.Sheets[sheet_name];
    var cell_b1 = sheet_A['B1'].v;
    console.log("B1: " + cell_b1);
    
}
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with this library, but by quickly scanning its documentation it says that it doesn't automatically compute formula results. Maybe reading the [section about formulae](https://www.npmjs.com/package/xlsx#formulae) will help?

Comment: In Excel, the worksheet normally has `Calculate` method, which will update all formulas in the worksheet.